# Detect SMS read on Android

Tags: android, events, notifications, sms, broadcastreceiver

Is there an event that can be captured by a BroadcastReceiver for a new SMS that has just been opened and getting read? Alternatively, can this be done by capturing perhaps the event of the  "new message" notification going away from the notification bar? The only similar question I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709335/is-there-a-good-way-to-tell-when-an-sms-gets-read-on-android).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an event that can be captured by a BroadcastReceiver for a new SMS that has just been opened and getting read?

There are many SMS clients -- you will have to contact each of their authors individually and ask them. Android as an OS does not have the concept of SMSes being "opened" or "read". The Messaging application that is part of the Android open source project has no documented and supported broadcasts.

> Alternatively, can this be done by capturing perhaps the event of the "new message" notification going away from the notification bar?

No, sorry.